# method similar to array#pop for hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash of people keyed by job and sorted by salary:

```
person = Struct.new(:salary)

people = {
  :butchers => [
    person.new(10),
    person.new(6),
    person.new(4)
  ],
  :bakers => [
    person.new(16),
    person.new(8),
    person.new(7)
  ],
  :candlestick_makers => [
    person.new(25),
    person.new(21),
    person.new(18)
  ]
}
```

I want to remove the last x people of each job from their respective array and do something:

```
def this_example_method
  people.each do |job, people|
    people.pop(number_for(job)).each do |person|
      #do something
    end
  end
end
```

the 'do something' works okay, but `pop` removal doesn't.  After running `this_example_method`, the `people` hash **should** look this, but at the moment it's not changing:

```
people = {
  butchers = [
    <butcher_1 salary:10>
    <butcher_2 salary:6>
  ],
  bakers = [
    <baker_1 salary:16>
    <baker_2 salary:8>
  ],
  candlestick_makers = [
    <candlestick_maker_1 salary:25>
    <candlestick_maker_2 salary:21>
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does not hash people give you syntax error?

Comment: Your expression is invalid.

Comment: @AlokAnand I think, it is an example to show how data he is having from any source..

Comment: @ArupRakshit, you're right, but it should be valid syntax.  fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as below :

```
def this_example_method
  people.each do |job, persons|
    persons.tap { |ob| ob.pop(x) }.each do |person|
      #do something
    end
  end
end
```

Example :

```
hash = { :a => [1,2,3], :b => [3,5,7] }
hash.each do |k,v|
  v.tap(&:pop).each { |i| # working wit i }
end

hash # => {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 5]}
```

Comment: i was using a reverse that seems to make pop not work...i changed it to `reverse!` and it was fine.  thanks :)

Comment: @dax Don't need to *reverse*, then you could do `people.tap(&:shift)`

Answer (score 2):

Hash has a `shift` method that returns the first item and removes it from the hash. If the order matters you could perhaps try to sort it reversed when the hash is created.

Comment: nice idea, but the keys still need to be available - i only want to remove the values